# Replace the string in all lines of itab?

Tags: string, abap

I am trying to create an algorithm in SAP ABAP to eliminate the word IBAN from certain fields. For example, in the below photo we have that for `KNBK-Bankschlüssel=7415000`, the `KNBK-Bankkontonummer= <IBAN 000000000008`. I am trying to eliminate IBAN from the field so that only 000000000008 will be shown in the table.

[image]

Is there any string operation that would let me check whether a field has the keyword IBAN and to eliminate it?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility is [`REPLACE IN TABLE`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-us/abapreplace_itab.htm):

```
REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF REGEX '^.*IBAN>'
 IN TABLE itab WITH ''
 RESPECTING CASE.
```

This snippet will delete all the `<IBAN>`s with all the preceding characters from all lines.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with the REPLACE statement:

```
IF word CS 'IBAN'.                    "to check if the string contains IBAN (as substring)
  REPLACE 'IBAN' WITH '' INTO word.   "This will remove the substring IBAB, but it will be replaced with a space
  CONDENSE word NO-GAPS.              "This will remove the space (and other spaces as well, if there is any in the string)
ENDIF.
```

Looking at the screenshot, the field contains '< IBAN>' (instead of just 'IBAN'), so you have to modify the code accordingly.